# Liquibase Maven plugin: Getting "table doesn't exist" error when trying to drop all tables

Tags: maven, liquibase, sql-drop, xmltable

We're using Maven 3.0.4 with the Liquibase  2.0.5 Maven plugin.  We have this set up to clear all tables from our test database:

```
               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <!-- To guarantee our test db is pure, drop all tables, before re-creating
                            the test db. -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>drop-tables-before-running-liquibase</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <propertyFile>${liquibase.properties.path}</propertyFile>
                                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                            </configuration>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>dropAll</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

However, upon executing the above, the script dies with

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:2.0.5:dropAll (drop-tables-before-running-liquibase) on project database: Error setting up or running Liquibase: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'test_db2.test_annotation' doesn't exist -> [Help 1]

This is an odd error because when I log in to the database in question, the table is there.  Any advice on how to solve this or troubleshoot it more deeply?

Comment: Is mysql on windows or linux? It may be a case sensitivity issue. 3.0+ versions of liquibase tend to handle that a bit better.

Comment: If it's a case sensitivity issue, it might be on the database side and not liquibase's fault.  I just had a similar issue where my linux-specific distro of mysql died when you did selects from a table where the table was improperly cased.  *sigh* I thought databases were always case insensitive unless you put things in quotes...  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html